# Tooltips for any text

Tags: quarto

I would like to add tooltips to certain bits of text to display additional information.

Tooltips in quarto seems to be automatically created for citations and [footnotes](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/footnotes-and-citations.html#footnotes). Is it possible to create tooltips manually for any random text, similar to the use of bold, italic etc?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a direct way, but you could use the [`tippy`](https://tippy.john-coene.com/index.html) package for this:

````
---
format: html
---

This is a [normal distribution]{id='normaldist'}.

```{r}
#|echo: false
tippy::tippy_this(elementId = "normaldist", tooltip = "Also called Gaussian distribution.")
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Answer from  Mickaël Canouil. https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/5225

> Tooltip is a HTML feature.
> Quarto is using Bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/tooltips/).
> You can find many examples on the Internet that you can adapt to your needs.
>
> Note that, for something "similar" to bold/italics/etc. I suggest you create a shortcode Quarto extension, see https://quarto.org/docs/extensions/shortcodes.html.
>
> Edit: you could also use the NutShell Quarto extension, see https://github.com/schochastics/quarto-nutshell.

Comment: So, Mickaël Canouil's answer is, essentially "google it". Very helpful for quarto users who are not html/css experts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works with R. Based on bootstrap [tooltip docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/).

[image]

````
---
title: r tooltip
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
tt <- function(x, y) {
    paste0('<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="',y,'">',x,'</a>')
}
```

This is some random text with a tooltip `r tt("here","This is great")` and a tooltip `r tt("there","Fantastic")`.
````